# How to hide id in page routing in asp.net 4.0?

Tags: asp.net

Using page route i had created following URL

http://www.domain.com/products/xyz/1.aspx

but i want rename above url as

http://www.domain.com/products/xyz.aspx

i donot want show id in url but also able to access is in other page using Page route.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> i donot want show id in url but also able to access is in other page
>   using Page route.

If you donot want to pass "id" in the url & you want "id" on your page, then you have to retrieve it based on the other parameter that you have passed in the url.

Eg. You can pass unique product name in the url & the retrieve product id based on the product name form the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HttpContext.Current.RewritePath` method in order to rename your url

Link : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2538/URL-Rewriting-with-ASP-NET

Comment: Thanks for this solutions but i want it through Page Routing. Is it possible?